# Кавычится ли название произведения в подписи к иллюстрации?

Tags: пунктуация

> Фра Филиппо Липпи. Благовещение. 1440 г.
>
> Палаццо Барберини.
> Национальная галерея старинного искусства. Рим.

Речь о "Благовещении".

У года создания принято ли ставить сокращённое "г."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Снял с полки пару энциклопедических изданий хорошего качества. Во всех используется один шаблон: название без кавычек, буква "г." вообще не ставится — только точка после года (вот так: 1440.). Даже в таком варианте: "350–340 до н.э.".